# Water flow looks like drops

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, subdivision-surface

Im a beginner to blender, so some settings are a bit confusing to me, please be kind enough to guide me to sort out this issue.

In this animation, I cannot generate a water flow which looks realistic. It always falls down as **drops**. (velocity is not an issue, they are flowing fast) but the water flowing falling down as big droplets. How can i change this ?

Your support is highly appreciated :) Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With fluid sim it is important to ensure your settings reflect the desired physical properties - in particular the Time and the Real World Size - in order to get convincing behaviour from the fluid.

Assuming you’re rendering 250 frames at 25 frames per second you should set End time to 10 (10 seconds for the whole simulation).

Also, it appears that your mesh is some kind of large scale water conduit but your Real World Scale is only 0.5 metres - set it to something more applicable for the scale of your simulation (it defines the real world dimension of the longest dimension of your domain).

Once you have this set you may also need to re-adjust the rate of flow from your Inflow to match the new scales.

The Time and Size setting will affect properties such as effect of gravity, surface tension/viscosity, friction, etc. Which will affect the behaviour of the fluid.